# How to fix Xcode error: Value of type 'AVAudioRecorder?' has no member 'URL'

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm a Udacity iOS Developer student, working on the app PitchPerfect that records and plays back audio. I'm using Xcode 10.2.1 along with the simulator, and Swift 4. I have been following the class instructions closely, but am getting an error with code in my RecordSoundsViewController.swift. My build keeps failing. I am receiving the following error:

Value of type 'AVAudioRecorder?' has no member 'URL'

I would love your suggestions on how to move forward, and get my build to compile.

I tried updating my Xcode version (to the current version I'm running, 10.2.1) and switching to Swift 4.2 but that didn't seem to help.

```
//
//  RecordSoundsViewController.swift
//  PitchPerfect
//
//  Created by Shara Karasic on 6/1/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Shara Karasic. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController,       AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var recordedAudioURL:URL!

    @IBOutlet weak var recordingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopRecordingButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print ("viewWillAppear called")
    }

    @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        recordingLabel.text = "Recording in progress"
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
        recordButton.isEnabled = false

        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)

        try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()
    }
    @IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
        recordButton.isEnabled = true
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        recordingLabel.text = "Tap to Record"
        audioRecorder.stop()
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! audioSession.setActive(false)
    }
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "stopRecording", sender: audioRecorder.URL)
        } else {
            print ("recording was not successful")
        }
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "stopRecording" {
            let playSoundsVC = segue.destination as! PlaySoundsViewController
            let recordedAudioURL  = audioRecorder.url
            playSoundsVC.recordedAudioURL = recordedAudioURL
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this code to run smoothly, especially as I got it directly from the Udacity course, but my build fails and I get the error:

Value of type 'AVAudioRecorder?' has no member 'URL'

Comment: Hint: Case matters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be outdated, `url` is lowercased, and use the passed `recorder` parameter

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "stopRecording", sender: recorder.url)
```

it's always worth it to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder)

---

And these four lines won't work at all (`URL(string` is inappropriate) and it's a horrible way to concatenate paths

```
let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))
```

Replace it with

```
let dirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let fileURL = dirURL.appendingPathComponent("recordedVoice.wav")

...

try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: fileURL, settings: [:])
```

Side note: It's discouraged to `try!` unless the code cannot crash (like in the `FileManager` line)

Comment: I tried the above and still got the same error. :-( Do you mean delete the original four lines and replace with your two lines only, and then replace the try! audioRecorder line with your new line?

Comment: If you use `recorder.url` the error must go away. Yes, replace the original 4 lines with my 2 and use `fileURL` in the `audioRecorder` line.

Comment: Oh, I fixed it by changing "URL" in audioRecorder.url to lower case in two places. Then the build succeeded. Thank you!